# Unable to install any windows (8, 8.1 or 10 ) on my laptop due to BSOD errors

Tags: windows-10, boot-partition

At the beginning I was on Windows 10 64-bit version and I installed Kali 2.0 on separate drive. However, I unfortunately was unable to boot Kali through bootloader so I mistakenly deleted all partitions from my laptop.

Now I have a full 931 GB of space but when I tried to install Windows 10 again through USB it shows error "page_fault_in_non_paged_area" and sometimes it shows "memory management error" (photo attached).

Error shows before "Install Now" option so I'm unable to go into partition and repair option. It is happening with all Windows 8, 8.1 and 10. But when i tried to install Windows 7, it installed successfully but mouse pointer, USB devices, DVD-ROM, any other drivers wasn't working except keyboard.

So I'm stuck in the position where i can't install any windows. (I tried Linux Mint as it install successfully but later I removed it) .

Model: Asus R558UR

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"page_fault_in_non_paged_area" and "memory management error" errors (especially when seen on the same machine performing the same/similar actions) almost always point to bad RAM.

Download the Windows installer again (to ensure your first image downloaded wasn't corrupted), try it with a different USB stick (to ensure it's not eh USB stick causing the problem).  If the same errors persist, then [start testing your RAM](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: +1 for getting a known good Windows installer, USB and checking the memory. If all that checks out, running a bootable disk diagnostic might be warranted, like Seatools.